# Cannot run programs as sudo from launcher

Tags: command-line, bash, launcher

I am trying to create a launcher with this command input:

`gksu sh -c "~/evelauncher/evelauncher.sh"`

but it fails. When I enter:

`sudo ~/evelauncher/evelauncher.sh`

in terminal it works perfectly (with text output) and starts the program. Can someone explain why the launcher doesnt work? The launcher has read-write access as my user, and the "execute files as programs" checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command instead (replacing `YOURUSERNAME` with the appropriate value):

```
gksu sh /home/YOURUSERNAME/evelauncher/evelauncher.sh
```

First, it replaces the `~` with your actual absolute home directory path.
Second, you don't need to pass the script path as command string to `sh`, it can directly interpret script files.

Answer (score 1):

Tilde (`~`) doesn't expand inside quotes. You could remove the quotes:

```
gksu sh ~/evelauncher/evelauncher.sh
```

Or use `$HOME` instead:

```
gksu sh "$HOME/evelauncher/evelauncher.sh"
```